# How to minify html, css and js of custom elements?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to create some custom elements without Polymer like the below code.

**demo-element.html**

```
<template id="demo-template">
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            background-color: #F2CEE5;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <div><content></content></div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
            createdCallback: {
                value: function() {
                    var t = document.querySelector('#demo-template');
                    var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
                    this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
                }
            }
        });
        var element = document.registerElement('demo-element', {prototype: proto});
    })();
</script>
```

Any good solution to minify those html components?
I always use UglifyJS in NodeJS to minify js files by the way.

Comment: Maybe gzipping is enough for a server supporting SPDY?

Answer (score 1):

Polymer's [vulcanize](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) tool worked for me on a project with non-Polymer web components.

Comment: Vulcanize is just for concatenating them into one file, isn't it? I don't really want to concatenate them but minify each one of them.

Comment: The vulcanize `--strip` flag will get you half way there but it doesn't shorten JavaScript variables like uglify. On average it cuts my file size down to about 2/3 the initial size. It's a good start.

Comment: I've started leaning toward using a separate JS, HTML, and CSS file (as needed) for each web component, and if you do that you could uglify your JS files first then use vulcanize with the `--strip` flag.